# How to handle EOF when have a string of NUL characters

Tags: c#, file, eof

I am reading a file using this
`while ((line = f1.ReadLine()) != null)`
however my program can't handle the last line which always have this in debugger "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0....on and on"
what is the best way to handle this?

```
while ((line = f1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                doing abc

              }
```

when I run debugger it 's still going inside the loop and doing abc. ofcouse it fails because there is nothing in the line

Comment: "my program can't handle the last line" - can you describe how it "can't handle it"?  What happens specifically, and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Could you post more of the code with maybe a link to the file you're reading?  At first thought it could be maxing out a buffer or something and you may need to parse the file using a stream, reading portions at a time.

Comment: it is a simple file reading, it's suppose to stop when it finds a null. but apparently not

Comment: Is it a Text file (at all / fully) ?

Comment: Could you post some of your code and the file you're parsing?

Comment: Is the file you're reading simultaneously being written to by another process, like a live log file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a string of `null`:

```
'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`
```

Isn't == `null`. You could try something like this:

```
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = f1.ReadLine()))
{
  if (line[0]=='\0') {
    /// strings should rarely start with null, so feel feel to break out of your loop here.
  }
  else
  {
    // found some real content, so process normally.
  }
}
```

I'm not a fan of those type of checks, though. Hopefully someone else will have a better suggestion.

A better question might be: Why am I getting a massively-long string of nulls when reading a text file line-by-line?

Comment: the text file is given. I cant change anything. when I open the txt fine using notepad++ I can see that the last line has null nullnull null etc on and on

Comment: @JohnRyann just occurred to me: technically this makes it not a real text file. Even if most of the content is text and control chars (new line, etc.), what your describing is binary data, no matter how asinine. Is this for school?